# how to do server side form validation for dynamic inputs with Django

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

I am using `django.forms.Form` to validate form data in a survey applications.

In a survey-creating form, a user can submit multiple questions that belong to the survey being created.

Names for the question inputs are in the form of 'question_`seq`' , where `seq` is maintained using Javascript.

Back in the server side, my code doesn't know before hand how many such questions will be submitted.

Is there any way to do this with Django form so that the form can automatically recognizes the `questions` and validate them?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for [formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#id1)